# import js file (to use php data) in my ts file

Tags: angular

I need to call a php data to initialise an angular 2 page as
 typescript file so i want to import the php data (which is an array) but i need > it in the same page so i can't use http get method.
 To do it i thought about importing php file (or php data) to a javascript
 variable so i need to import this file to my typescript file to manipulate
 the data and show it in my page  Can anybody helps me because i didn't
 find how to do it in the typescript file...

For example : i have this code of php that i need to call it and return the resulat :

```
<?php  

include_once("www-apps/backbone/_core/DslamCardRessources.cls.php");
$aListSites = DslamCardRessources::GetListSites();
$i=0;
foreach($aListSites as $key => $value)
{
    $tab_liste[$i] = $key."=>".$value;
    $i++;
}

?>
```

i thought i can use it directly in my typescript file but i didn't find a solution so i thought maybe i will try to pass it by a javascript file so i added this line

```
<?php echo "var liste_site = \"".implode(",", $tab_liste)."\".split(',');"; ?>
```

so now i need to use this "liste_site" variable in my typescript file. this variable is an array and i want to put those values in my select component.

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: ok i will update my question